# Blender is crashing on launch

Tags: error

I've been using Blender for about a year now without issue, but haven't used it in the last few months. I went to open one of my .blender files today and it just froze up. I tried a few times with the same result. I then started a new project and appended the models I needed from the other file. This worked until I pressed Shift+Z and then it crashed. I then tried again and it crashed before I could even select append. I've now downloaded the latest build (I had 'a' before, so now I have 'c'), and it's crashing the second it launches. It's the same computer* I've had the whole time, so I'm not sure why Blender has decided to stop working all of a sudden. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

*I'm on a 2013 iMac with a 3.2GHz processor and 16GB RAM, running Sierra.

Comment: Crashes should be reported to the [official bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/) if they can be reliably reproduced so that the developers can fix them rather than here.

Comment: But what about other files/objects, does it crash if opening them?

Comment: I can't even open anything at this point. It's either crashing upon launch or freezing directly after.

Comment: Is there any output in the terminal? (Provided you are launching from it)

Comment: I don't know how to use the terminal.